# How to get the total allocated size of the files inside a folder on Windows

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, kvm-switch, vhd

I have a SMB share in which I keep a bunch of dynamic VHD and QCOW2 images used as volumes for virtual machines. This share is supposed to be used by Hyper-V as well as KVM nodes.

I'd like to know the total disk space allocated to those images. Is there any command similar to "du -sb --aparent-size" from Linux to do this on Windows?

For the moment, I'm using qemu-img and the WMI instrumentation in a Python script to do this but it is kind of slow for large number of images. It takes about a few minutes to do this task.

The idea is that this status should be reported quite frequently (every 10 minutes for example) so I'd need it done in less than 30 seconds.

I'd gladly appreciate if someone could give me a better way of doing this, in a shorter time.

Answer (score 0):

Is using Cygwin an option? That should give you access to `du`.

Comment: Not quite, unfortunately. This is part of a bigger project and I was hoping for some WMI alternatives.

Comment: That's fair. It's out of my depth, but perhaps PowerShell can get you somewhere.